# Is there any feature/API of sendgrid that is not offered in its integration with Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, sendgrid

Sendgrid is its only standalone product.  Then there is Sendgrid integrated with Google App Engine.  Is there any feature or API available in standalone Sendgrid (E.g. Event API / Webhooks) that is not available in the SendGrid integrated with Google App Engine?

Comment: I recommend getting an actual SendGrid account. Like @kekito said, it's not _really_ integrated, and from my own experience SendGrid integrations with platform services are crippled. They miss out on key features like the SendGrid Events API. Without it you can't track opens/clicks on your end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SendGrid isn't really integrated with App Engine.  You use the same SendGrid APIs regardless of whether you are calling them from App Engine or somewhere else.

SendGrid does have several pricing plans (Bronze, Silver, etc.) and one of the pricing plans is specific to App Engine because of a marketing agreement with Google.  SendGrid has a detailed explanation of the features for each plan [here](https://sendgrid.com/partner/google).

It isn't clear to me whether the "App Engine" plan is explicitly restricted to use from App Engine.  They could do some IP address filtering but I expect they do not so that anyone could use the App Engine plan.